# SQLite Indexing

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am unable to decide about Indexing. 
Like I have below query which taking too much time for executing:

```
select count(rn.NODE_ID) as Count,
       rnl.[ISO_COUNTRY_CODE] as Country,
       rnl.[FUNCTIONAL_CLASS] as Functional_Class
from RDF_NODE as rn,
     RDF_LINK as rl,
     RDF_NAV_LINK as rnl 
where rl.[LINK_ID] = rnl.[LINK_ID]
  AND rn.NODE_ID IN (rl.[NONREF_NODE_ID], rl.[REF_NODE_ID])
GROUP BY rnl.[ISO_COUNTRY_CODE],
         rnl.[FUNCTIONAL_CLASS]
```

While I use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN:

```
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE RDF_NODE AS rn USING COVERING INDEX NODE (~1000000 rows)
0 1 2 SCAN TABLE RDF_NAV_LINK AS rnl (~6645278 rows)
0 2 1 SEARCH TABLE RDF_LINK AS rl USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_RDF_LINK_1 (LINK_ID=?) (~1 rows)
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

All the tables having Indexing.

What is the difference between SCAN and SEARCH?
do we able to Change the Order?

Comment: What are the indexes?

Comment: `SCAN` is the operation in which all rows have to be iterated
`SEARCH` seems to be what is called `SEEK` in SQL Server where proper index usage is possible and not all rows have to be iterated to find the right one

Comment: And that makes sense, because this `from RDF_NODE as rn, RDF_LINK as rl, RDF_NAV_LINK as rnl` is a cross join and it makes total sense to iterate over all rows in those tables to cross join them, but probably an `INNER JOIN` would meet your needs more efficiently.

Comment: 1. RDF_NODE table **NODE** is indexed on NODE_ID column. . .. 2. RDF_NAV_LINK table **Whatever** is indexed on LINK_ID column although the same column is primary_id.... 3. RDF_LINK table **NX_RDF_LINK_NREFNODE** on NONREF_NODE_ID and **NX_RDF_LINK_REFNODE** on REF_NODE_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SCAN goes through all rows in a table (in the order they are stored in the table, which is usually no order at all), while a SEARCH looks up single rows from a table.

SQLite implements all joins as nested loop joins.
The outermost table is always accessed through a SCAN (except when there is a WHERE clause that restricts the rows to be returned).
All the remaining tables should be accessed with a SEARCH to look up matching records; another SCAN indicates that there is no index that can used to speed up the lookup, so finding each match requires searching the entire table.

---

For this particular query, a large slowdown is the temporary table used to implement the GROUP BY.
If all the grouping columns are in a single index, this is not necessary:

```
CREATE INDEX UseABetterIndexNameHere
    ON RDF_NAV_LINK(ISO_COUNTRY_CODE, FUNCTIONAL_CLASS);
```

(The join between `RDF_NAV_LINK` and `RDF_LINK` requires that `RDF_LINK` rows are looked up by their `LINK_ID`, so this column needs an index.
Similarly, `RDF_NODE` needs an index on `NODE_ID`. But these indexes already exist.)